# Openshift: OSError Errno 98 can't update server

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web, openshift

I'm using Openshift with Django/Python 3. As of yesterday, I've been unable to update my server. When I push a change, the push is successful. Using SCP to view the files on the server, the updated files are present. Using rhc git-pull downloads the correct files as well. However, the templates are the only thing that actually get changed on the app by the push. No changes to python files cause an effect on the app.

When I try to use 'rhc tail', I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Searching this error leads me to believe there are multiple server processes running for my app. I'm not sure how to run suggested diagnostics, as I don't control the server. Any ideas? Restarting the app does not fix it. Running rhc stop appears to successfully stop the app, yet my website works unhindered. (I've never tried stopping before, but assume it's supposed to kill the website.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this post this afternoon by somebody having the same problem.  It looks like Openshift  changed some things on us.  I didn't get the memo :(.

Read here:
[Openshift March Blog post](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog)

@MSDOS,  it is similar to your answer but I wanted to post the generic answer that is probably affecting most people.

For me,  I just had to rename app.py (my old wsgi entry point) to wsgi.py and everything worked as it should. :)  Now I have to figure what they changed to the cron jobs :(

Comment: Thank you - it looks like this was the problem. It's great news that they ditched the forced directory structure. I'd love to set my directories up Django standard. Any advice on how to do so, or an example? I currently get 'FileNotFoudnError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wsgi/application' on rhc tail when I try.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I  filed the bugzilla report thinking its a bug or at least get some help. They say it's not a bug but still have not shown the correct way to do it. Very frustrating.  Maybe we can solve it together.  Keep posting here until we can figure out better communication method.

Comment: I set up a new openshift app, and cloned into it. Of note, there's a file called wsgi.py that might be the key. When I load my django files into the newly created app, commit and push, I don't get  errors, and am sent to a "Welcome to your Python application" page, thats HTML is inside wsgi.py. Let me know if you have any luck with that file.

Comment: Here's wsgi.py: https://github.com/David-OConnor/squadron/blob/ef67c189b5fa06162fb513a6b28a9c96f6d985ea/test/wsgi.py

Comment: Wsgi.py is the key.  Can you contact me at fatfantasma@gmail.com? It might be easier to communicate by email instead of junking up this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by executing 'rhc app force-stop', then 'rhc app start'. I don't know what caused the problem, but force-stopping it killed the website, and it worked with the new code after starting it again.

Comment: I wouldn't say the problem is solved. It still exists. You found the same work around as I did. I hope they fix it.

Comment: You're right - not solved. I ran rhc tail again, and it worked for a bit - minutes later, rhc tail drops the same error as before. I bet I'll have to force stop/start it next push again.

Comment: Yes. You will have to 'rhc app-force-stop' before you push every time now until they fix it. I hope the openshift guys are reading this ;)

Comment: @TurtlesAreCute How exactly did you call `rhc app-force-stop?` I'm having the exact same problem, and this workaround didn't work. I'm starting to think PaaS as openshift isn't that great, if I was using a VPS configured by myself...

Comment: @fatfantasma Are you using Turtles Are Cute workaround? It isn't working for me...

Comment: I have been on vacation and not been able to check. Before I left last week I had to rhc app-force- stop to get a push to work.  I was hoping they would have fixed it by now. I am also surprised there has been no official post here or the thread I started on same issue by openshift. It makes you wonder if anybody is driving the bus. I should be able to test thus Sat. I do know my crons jobs are not working also. Openshift has issues and they are very silent :(

Comment: MS-DOS, I used cd in a terminal to change to local Openshift directory, then entered 'rhc app force-stop'.

Comment: I've tried everything, every order of these commands, and I can't get it to work. And `rhc tail` doesn't show errors anymore. I just get "Error 500" in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem.

I was using an old django repository, based on https://github.com/openshift/openshift-community-cartridge-python-3.3/blob/master/template/app.py (the link is dead, I mentioned here just for information).

In these old community cartridges, there was a `app.py` file that started CherryPy or httpd, but now the official django repository doesn't have app.py anymore. (check https://github.com/openshift/django-example)

The `app.py` doesn't exist anymore because `httpd` service was added automatically. That's why we were having `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`.

Removing the `app.py` from my repository solved the problem.

I was receiving error 500 because my Django application was having errors, not my Python cartridge. That's why I wasn't understanding what was happening. I did a `find . -name *.log*` in my cartridge and read all logs.

Now my app is working. Good luck!

Comment: @msdos,  I'm now getting the error when I try to create a new app with the exact same code as my working app.  You mentioned that the httpd service was added automatically which seems to be the problem.  Can that be disabled? I wanted to run my own "waitress" server.

Comment: Hum, I have no idea. When I created a Python App, since it's their Python cartridge, running `ps ax | grep python` the server httpd is already running. I do believe if you want to run your own "waitress" server you'll be stuck with a custom cartridge... :/ or try to kill (don't know if it's possible) the httpd services in a post_start-python3.3 or equivalent script.

Comment: Before the march 14 change, the user always started the server (waitress, cherrypy, simple_server). I don't know if it's a bug or they have totally changed the way they do things.  I'm totally stuck. :(

Comment: I push my app today without the error. They must have fixed if.