# Openshift: App fails to start after push due to OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, python-3.x, openshift, socketexception

As of yesterday, 3/12/2014 I started getting errors pushing my free Python 3.3, Mongodb, cron app to the Openshift server.  There error is

```
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I can get the app to push and run correctly if I do a 'rhc app-force-stop' first then to my push everytime(pain in the butt).  It seems like push is no longer stopping the app before the push and restart.

Everything was working fine yesterday morning so the issue has cropped up in the last 24 hours.

Any comments from the Openshift team? Is this a temporary bug?  I see others are having the same issue posted in stackoverflow.

Comment: That error means there's another instance or your program already running and holding the socket (or a different program using the same port number).

Comment: Correct. However, when you push to openshift it should stop the current app, push, restart.   I don't think the stop is happening anymore. Bug!

Comment: Since it works with "force-stop" I suppose your app blocks when it receives the basic "stop" event and continues to run (and hold the socket open). With force stop it completely kills the app's process so the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: I think openshift's initial 'stop' call on push is not working correctly currently. Other people are having the same problem. They need to fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Openshift: OSError Errno 98 can't update server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383501/openshift-oserror-errno-98-cant-update-server)