# Openshift: Cron job fails to run

Tags: openshift

As of yesterday, 3/12/2014 my cron job for my free python 3.3, mongodb, cron app on Openshift stopped running.  Everything was working fine until late afternoon.   I can still run the cron job manually without error.

The execution bit is set. I wouldn't think I have run out of processing time since I can run it manually. I'm not sure if it's related to this issue:

[Openshift app push error 98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393217/openshift-app-fails-to-start-after-push-due-to-oserror-errno-98-address-alre)

Both issue started at the same time.  Any ideas?

Comment: So, you've had 12 months to work on this. What did you find?   In fact, how do you run the cron job manually?

Comment: I believe it was just an Openshift issue that cleared itself up after a couple of days.  I have wasted many many hours on Openshift bugs over the years ; )  Regarding running manually I just meant running the python script from the command line. You might want to do a app-force-stop and reset everything.  That sometimes clears up the Openshift problem.

Comment: Hey I did figure out how to run manually. The format is `node $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/serverTest.js`